# Checking if word is palindrome with function

Tags: algorithm, pascal, palindrome

I have to write a program in Pascal which checks whether a word is a palindrome.

For example:

> if I input "abba" then write 'TRUE'
>
> input 'abb a' then write 'TRUE'
>
> input 'abca' write 'FALSE'

I wrote this:

```
program palindromek;

var i,j,delka,pul:integer;
str:string;
function   palindrom(slovo:string):boolean;

const mezera=32;

begin
    delka:=length(str);

    if (delka mod 2) = 0 then pul:=delka div 2
    else pul:=(delka-1) div 2;

    for i:=1 to delka do
    begin
        if (ord(slovo[i])>=ord('a')) and (ord(slovo[i])<=ord('z')) then
        begin
            if (delka>=4)and(delka<=100) then
                begin
                if (length(str) mod 2) = 0 then {slovo se sudym poctem pismen}
                begin
                for j:=1 to pul do
                    begin
                    if slovo[j]=slovo[length(str)-j+1]
                    then palindrom:=true else palindrom:=false
                    end
                end else
                begin
                    for j:=1 to pul do
                    begin
                        if slovo[j]=slovo[length(str)-j+1]
                        then palindrom:=true else palindrom:=false
                    end
                end
            end else if slovo[1]=slovo[delka]
            then palindrom:=true else palindrom:=false
        end
 end;
end;
begin
 readln(str);
 writeln(palindrom(str));
end.
```

but it has to ignore spaces. Do you have any idea please?

Comment: Strip out all the spaces before you start the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot read your language, so I am not going to read your code.  Just strip out all whitespace and convert to all uppercase before starting to compare characters.

Comment: I know that I have to strip out the whitespace, but I don't know how can I do it :)

Answer (score 1):

To remove all spaces, you can use function like this:

```
procedure RemoveSpacesInplace(var s: string);
var
  i, SpaceCount: Integer;
begin
  SpaceCount := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
    if s[i] = ' ' then
      Inc(SpaceCount)
    else
      s[i - SpaceCount] := s[i];
  SetLength(s, Length(s) - SpaceCount);
end;
```

You can modify it for other non-letter chars.

Note that your logic for odd and even length is excessive. Try to simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions StringReplace and ReverseString for your task.

```
program palindromek;
uses SysUtils, StrUtils;

var
  str:string;

function   palindrom(slovo:string):boolean;
begin
    slovo := StringReplace(slovo, ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Result := slovo = ReverseString(slovo)
end;
begin
 readln(str);
 writeln(palindrom(str));
 readln;
end.
```

If you are not allowed to use SysUtils and StrUtils then you can manually reverse your string and then compare if the original string and the reversed string are equal.

This would look something like this: (not tested!)

```
function   palindrom(slovo:string):boolean;
var slovofor: string;
    slovorev: string;
    i: integer;
begin
    for i:= length(slovo) downto 1 do begin
      if slovo[i] <> ' ' then begin
        slovofor := slovofor + slovo[length(slovo)-i+1];
        slovorev := slovorev + slovo[i];
      end;
    end;
    writeln(slovofor);
    Result := slovofor = slovorev
end;
```